# varnish ignore haproxy session affinity cookie

Tags: haproxy, varnish

I have HAproxy behind varnish and I need use session affinity based on cookies. 
In default configuration, varnish doesn't cache content when the cookie is present.

Anyone knows, how to tell varnish "ignore this cookie: SERVERID"?

I found this, but I don't have these directives in my config:
[How to make Varnish ignore, not delete cookies](https://serverfault.com/questions/205768/how-to-make-varnish-ignore-not-delete-cookies)

I can't remove this cookie, I need it on the haproxy for use correct server.

Varnish version = 3.0.7

Thanks